# Why google-collections contains semantically equal functions and strange generics?

Tags: java, generics, guava

Why google-collections or guava contains semantically equal functions? 
example:

```
static
<T> Predicate<T>
and(Predicate<? super T>... components) 

static
<T> Predicate<T>
and(Predicate<? super T> first, Predicate<? super T> second)
```

I.e. all functions that can accept several arguments.

The second question why do defintion of such functions use generic `<? super T>` instead of `<T>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the first question, the varargs version (`Predicate<? super T>...`) will give you a warning about the unchecked creation of a generic array when called with several generic predicates (e.g. `Predicate<T>`). For the common case of combining two predicates, you don't get that warning.

To answer the second question, taking `Predicate<? super T>` means you can pass in a `Predicate<Object>` (or `Predicate<Number>` or whatever) when calling the method to create a `Predicate<Integer>`. For example, if `Predicates.notNull()` were a `Predicate<Object>` (as it should be) and you wanted to combine that and some `Predicate<Integer>`, it would not be possible if the arguments were required to be of type `Predicate<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

First part is for performance, I believe.

In the second part it have to be `<? super T>`, because Guava allows you to put in any Predicate which can be evaluated on any super-type of T and T itself. Not only T itself as it would be with just `<T>`.
This makes sense due to the fact that a specific Predicate may be more general and is therefore defined on a more general type but you want to use it with some sub-type.

You see the same with the TreeSet Constructor: `TreeSet(Comparator<? super E> c)`.

Also have a look at [Generics Tutorial Page 18](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf)